# Pegar retorno do webservice xml - SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Estou acessando um webservice com SOAP e preciso pegar o conteúdo da tag -
 Mensagem

Segue retorno do webservice.

```
/var/www/html/particular/webservice/retphp:28:
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'Longout' => string '<WEBSERVICE_RET xmlns="">
    <Codigo>000</Codigo>
    <Mensagem>JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjzvU3VidHlwZS9JbWFnZS9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgvV2lkdGggMTc4L0xlbmd0aCA0MDA4L0hlaWdodCAxOTIvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KeJztnT+oJUkVxltEEEQEExkRRBBhEUwemBiLIBvJhouZD0QjBYMFwUzYwGgCB0QYFmRhWZARkwVZWEQZ6FCETUxkwVgwLu/cul23uuqcr05V17/uro/DcN99/edUnV99VdX33V2lhg6ix4eH1ikMdac+qZiuap3FSdUnElqf/PZJ6xTOqAsSPVOhro7ROoVzqX8k1LCLutoFEurqFRcwhmNU0F6Q0LpQMRyjtDQSO6JC28UAo7R2'... (length=20439)
```

Comment: a api devolveu essa string ? 

Tenta usar -- simplexml_load_string($string); 
Isso vai fazer a string virar xml e depois você acessar como array

Comment: blz, vou tentar.